# Why vuetify icon not showing?

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I using vuetify latest version. I following this tutorial https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start

In the vue componet I try like this :

```
  <v-text-field
    append-icon="mic"
    class="mx-4"
    flat
    hide-details
    label="Search"
    prepend-inner-icon="search"
    solo-inverted
  ></v-text-field>
```

The result like this :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByGYm.png)

In my public/index.html like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>msm-website-appointment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but msm-website-appointment doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

it looks like the design material has been loaded. but why doesn't the icon appear?

Answer (score 8):

You are probably referencing [`mdi`](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons#install-material-design-icons) (Material Design Icons font)  [according to the documentation](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons#install-material-design-icons), while your `v-text-field` is using a different one ([defaults to `md` in version `^1.5`](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons)), thus the missing icons.

To fix this issue, you'll want to add the [required icon font](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#install-material-icons), or if you will opt for `mdi`, do the following adjustments (note the icons property binding part being prefixed with `mdi-`):

```html
<v-text-field
  append-icon="mdi-microphone"
  class="mx-4"
  flat
  hide-details
  label="Search"
  prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
  solo-inverted>
</v-text-field>
```

As a side note, since you've initialized the app with Vue CLI, you no longer need to import the icons from the CDN as they will be taken care of by the build process, so feel free to remove it from your `public/index.html` file.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue, you should import mdi as your default icon set.
Otherwise, vuetify will not know where to load this icon from.
To do this, follow these steps:
Described in more detail in this article: https://www.the-koi.com/projects/how-to-set-up-a-project-with-nuxt3-and-vuetify3-with-a-quick-overview/

1. Install

   npm install @mdi/font
2. Import

   import* '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
3. Add

`const vuetify = createVuetify({ // Replaces new Vuetify(...) in vue3
    theme: {
        defaultTheme: 'dark'
    },
    icons: {
        defaultSet: 'mdi',
        aliases,
        sets: {
            mdi
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can also load it directly in the component in case the `mdi` package is missing in the build.

```
  <v-text-field
    :append-icon="icons.mdiMicrophone"
    class="mx-4"
    flat
    hide-details
    label="Search"
    :prepend-inner-icon="icons.mdiMagnify"
    solo-inverted
  />

<script>
import { mdiMicrophone, mdiMagnify } from '@mdi/js'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            icons: {
                mdiMicrophone
            }
        }
    }
}
```